# Sharepoint 2013: How do I restore the "All Items" view?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

I accidentally deleted the `"All Items"` view on my SP13 List page.  When I try to re-create it I get the error message "this view already exists." "All Items" does not appear in my dropdowns anywhere, or on the "List Settings" page.  I even checked recycle bin, not there.  Help??

Comment: did you try to create another all item view with different name and then make it default. once it worked then try to change the name of it.

Comment: also try to check the both level Recycle bin, this item will show with no title

Comment: What happens when you navigate to the page by manually adding /allitems.aspx after your list name in the address eg https://user.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Yes I tried to rename it, it gave me an error message.  Currently the view is named "all items2" but the site default for this page is "AllItems.aspx" so all the links on the site are broken. When I navigate to that page I am redirected to the "page not found" SP page.  Same when I type it in manually

Comment: OK, I resolved this using SP13 designer.  I basically just added "new" to the views and then typed in the original address.  I had to rename the display name in the code from SP13 as well, since the web page kept saying that name already existed.  All the old views were deleted 2 days ago.  The issue seems to be: where is SP13 keeping the graveyard of old deleted view names and links?  This is what needs to be addressed at this point.  Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

if I delete AllItems.aspx from the designer, I get it on the recycle bin:

**/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx**

with the name "(no title)" and the origin "Lists/mylistname"

you can also try

**/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx**

and

**/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2**

Comment: I deleted "AllItems.aspx" from SharePoint Designer 2013. When I accessed "/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx" with my credentials I didn't find anything. When I accessed it with "System Account", I found it :D

Comment: I cannot see the deteted view in suggested URL, even with Farm Administrator. What is the trick?

Comment: @Mark typically the problem is either wrong location or permissions. you may be accessing the wrong site. e.g. http://root/site1/site2/site3/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx VS http://root/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx also, if you try to re-create it it should fail, which will confirm it is recycled

Comment: @TiagoDuarte Is it SP2013 behaviour? I just try create a view test123. Then delete it and then re-create with same name. No problem at all and I cannot see it at recycle bin. I perform the test using site collection admin.

Comment: not sure. I guess you may either have recycling disabled in web application general settings (CA) or the method you are using to delete it, deletes it permanently

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, if you delete/overwrite (good, that this is possible from e.g. Word) your `AllItems.aspx` view, there are two good possibilities to get you out of troble:;

1. You have access to SharePoint Designer? Go to your library, delete the faulty AllItems.aspx and create a new view via SharePoint Designer.
2. Open your library in Explorer View and delete the faulty AllItems.aspx and copy over a fresh AllItems.aspx from another library.

The second method needs some explanation. You can access the `WebFldr.aspx` view? Great! Use this as explorer view. You can't? Open the library by attaching it as a network share in Windows Explorer (just use the full URL you know already). You need to enable hidden files/folder in Windows Explorer, then you will see the `Forms` folder. Open another library or create a new one and copy the `AllItems.aspx` file from the libraries `Forms` folder to your "broken" library `Forms` folder.